# How do I turn an ascii char into it's hex... thing in C++?

Tags: c++, hex

I have a program that includes this line:

```
  int xoredValue = (x ^ 0x41);
```

Where x is an int that I'm xoring with the binary form of both it and the hex code. The 0x41 is meant to represent an ascii letter. Instead of using 0x41, I want to make it

```
  char a = 'a';
  int xoredValue = (x ^ <hex of a>);
```

I've been trying to figure out how for a while and it's frying my noodle. Any help?

Comment: You should be able to just do `x ^ a`

Comment: Representation doesn't impact behavior here. `x & 0x41` is equivalent to `x & a`. Note that character `0x41` is `A` not `a`. `A`, `0x41` and `65` are all the same value.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! It worked lol

Comment: Hex is just a representation of a value.  hex,binary,octal, decimal that represents the same value will do the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.

**A number is a number is a number.**

`0x41` is a number, as is `65`, as is (counter-intuitively) `'A'`. Whether you give it in hex, or decimal, or even octal, is entirely irrelevant to the workings of the XOR operator, which works on *numbers*.

Your particular number is called `a` (because that's the name you gave the variable it's stored in).

So, just write `x ^ a`.

Comment: I wish there was a tautology flag. +1 for the lack of it.

Comment: Yeah I know, the reason I was saying about char a = 'a' is because I'm using a passed in array and I was just saying for example, since I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Me not realizing that I was using hex for 'A' instead of 'a' before  was a big part of the problem

Comment: gimme teh repppppzz